# If $G$ be a graph of order $6,$ then $G$ contains $C_3$ or $O_3$ as induced subgraph.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

If $G$ be a graph of order $6,$ then $G$ contains $C_3$ or $O_3$ as induced subgraph.

May I know if my proof is correct?

Suppose not. Let $v \in G.$ Consider the graph $H$ that is obtained by deleting $v$ and all edges incident to it. Since $H$ does not contain
$C_3$ or $O_3, H  = C_5.$  Now, if $v$ is adjacent to at least 3 vertices in $H,$ then we have a $C_3$ induced subgraph.  If not, we have a $O_3$ induced subgraph formed by $v$ and any two non-adjacent vertices (that are not adjacent to $v$).

Thank you.

Comment: What are $C_3$ and $O_3$?  Is one of them ozone?  And is the other one this molecule: http://www.lth.se/fileadmin/forbrf/Documents/Exjobb/Old/2002_Larsson_Thesis.pdf?

Comment: No. $C_3$ is cyclic graph of order 3 and $O_3$ is null graph.

Comment: I am not sure if the proof is complete.  While it is not difficult to show that a graph on $5$ vertices without a triangle or three non-adjacent vertices is a $5$-cycle, you haven't shown this (but you may have known this from other results already).  Otherwise, this looks correct.  However, your problem is just the same as saying that the Ramsey number $R(K_3,K_3)$ is $6$, also known as Ramsey's theorem (with multiple ways to prove).